# Python: How to ensure keys are type int

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, integer

In my code, I have a nested dictionary and I want to ensure that key `id` is an integer (note: it is a primary key). I tried just casting it to an `int` but I am unsure if the key is an `int` given that in the JSON there are double quotes.

See below my code and example of the data format.

```
statistics = defaultdict(dict)

\\in a loop
statistics[state][date].append({
                        int(id): {
                            "count_targets": targets,
                            "count_targets_excluded": excluded,
                            "count_targets_pending": pending,
                            "count_targets_in_progress": progress,
                            "count_targets_completed": completed,
                            "count_targets_failed": failed
                        }
                    })
```

```
{
  "stateA": {
    "2015-02-15": [
      {
        "13": {
          "count_targets": 5,
          "count_targets_excluded": 3,
          "count_targets_pending": 3,
          "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
          "count_targets_completed": 1,
          "count_targets_failed": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "14": {
          "count_targets": 4,
          "count_targets_excluded": 3,
          "count_targets_pending": 3,
          "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
          "count_targets_completed": 1,
          "count_targets_failed": 0
        }
      },
```

Comment: what do you mean by ensure? you can always check the type using `str.isnumeric("14")`

Comment: The key in your `dict` is certainly an `int`. JSON, however, only allows strings as object keys, so it has to convert it back. It's the *consumer* of the JSON (with the aid of a pre-defined schema) that has to be responsible for converting the key back to an `int`.

Comment: That is, `{3: 4}` is not a valid JSON object, only `{"3": 4}`.

Comment: @Epsi95: Never use string tests for this. Just call `int` on it, and handle the exception. The number of things that are validly parsable as `int` and the string tests won't catch (not without handling several special cases) is huge (e.g. `"-13"`, `"  14"`, `"14 "`, `"1_000"`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON objects can only use JSON strings as keys:

```
>>> json.dumps({3: 4})
'{"3": 4}'
```

While the key in you `dict` is certainly an `int`, it gets converted to a string when encoding as JSON. JSON itself doesn't have a way of "remembering" the original type of the value used as a key, so you need some method (extra data in your JSON object, a pre-defined schema, etc) that the *consumer* of the JSON can use to turn the key back into an `int` after decoding.

Answer (score 0):

JSON can not have ints as keys thus your ints get cast as string as soon as you convert your dictionary to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

> in the JSON there are double quotes.

You have what is called **Object** in JSON parlance, [RFC7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) situplates that

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.(...)

therefore, it will always have said quotes independently from type of key in `python` dict, consider that

```
import json
original = {1:100}
serialized = json.dumps(original)
deserialized = json.loads(serialized)
print(serialized)
print(original==deserialized)
```

gives output

```
{"1": 100}
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't produce legal JSON that has `int` keys, but if your goal is to *parse* incoming JSON with string keys that happen to represent valid `int`s (which you may or may not have generated in Python), and have them become true `int`s rather than `str`, you can do this:

```
def maybe_int(key):
    '''Converts strings that represent valid ints to int, leaving other strings unchanged'''
    try:
        return int(key)
    except ValueError:
        return key

def key_to_int(obj):
    '''Replaces all string keys representing valid ints with ints'''
    return {maybe_int(k): v for k, v in obj.items()}

 myjsonstr = '{"1": 2}'
 result = json.loads(myjsonstr, object_hook=key_to_int)
```

The hook is passed *every* decoded `dict` (aka JSON object), and that decoded `dict` is replaced by whatever the hook returns, in this case, a copy of the `dict` where any key that `int` can parse is replaced with its `int` value.